# Error problem: Column does not exist, while trying to perform an anova_test in R

Tags: r

I am working with R with a package that is call rstatix and I am trying to perform an anova test with the function anova_test. My data looks like this.

```
structure(
  list(
    Cat = c(
      "Mel",
      "Mel",
      "Mel",
      "Mel",
      "Mel",
      "Mel",
      "Mel",
      "Mel",
      "Mel",
      "Mel",
      "Mel",
      "Mel",
      "Mel",
      "Mel",
      "Mel",
      "Mel",
      "Mel",
      "Mel",
      "Mel",
      "Mel",
      "Mem",
      "Mem",
      "Mem",
      "Mem",
      "Mem",
      "Mem",
      "Mem",
      "Mem",
      "Mem",
      "Mem",
      "Mem",
      "Mem",
      "Mem",
      "Mem",
      "Mem",
      "Mem",
      "Mem",
      "Mem",
      "Mem",
      "Mem",
      "Men",
      "Men",
      "Men",
      "Men",
      "Men",
      "Men",
      "Men",
      "Men",
      "Men",
      "Men",
      "Men",
      "Men",
      "Men",
      "Men",
      "Men",
      "Men",
      "Men",
      "Men",
      "Men",
      "Men"
    ),
    count = c(
      66L,
      107L,
      185L,
      207L,
      203L,
      121L,
      41L,
      71L,
      147L,
      131L,
      38L,
      58L,
      175L,
      53L,
      76L,
      16L,
      154L,
      128L,
      27L,
      74L,
      85L,
      122L,
      51L,
      113L,
      182L,
      184L,
      92L,
      13L,
      151L,
      54L,
      174L,
      146L,
      192L,
      153L,
      138L,
      42L,
      116L,
      8L,
      148L,
      109L,
      129L,
      96L,
      179L,
      25L,
      418L,
      212L,
      358L,
      307L,
      240L,
      400L,
      22L,
      396L,
      211L,
      372L,
      30L,
      73L,
      176L,
      59L,
      128L,
      341L
    ),
    Word = c(
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA
    ),
    type_pro = c(
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM",
      "EM"
    ),
    total = c(
      3,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      1,
      1,
      0,
      0,
      2,
      3,
      0,
      3,
      2,
      1,
      0,
      0,
      1,
      2,
      3,
      1,
      4,
      5,
      5,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      3,
      3,
      5,
      4,
      4,
      3,
      3,
      4,
      4,
      4,
      4,
      4,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      2,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      1,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      1,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -60L),
  groups = structure(
    list(
      Cat = c("Mel", "Mem", "Men"),
      .rows = structure(
        list(1:20,
             21:40, 41:60),
        ptype = integer(0),
        class = c("vctrs_list_of",
                  "vctrs_vctr", "list")
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA, -3L),
    class = c("tbl_df",
              "tbl", "data.frame"),
    .drop = TRUE
  ),
  class = c("grouped_df",
            "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)
```

The problem is that I always get this error.

```
anova_test(total~Cat)
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `data`.
✖ Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `Cat` doesn't exist.
ℹ Input `data` is `map(.data$data, .f, ...)`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

If you see my data the column Cat exists. So I don't understand the error.

If someone can help me it would be great.

Comment: What's the name of your data object? According to the documentation for that function, you need to pass in the data as the first parameter. `anova_test(mydata, total~Cat)` or `mydata %>% anova_test( total~Cat)` or whatever your data.frame is named.

Comment: Yes, I am doing it like this, 

lol %>% anova_test(total~Cat)
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `data`.
✖ Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `Cat` doesn't exist.
ℹ Input `data` is `map(.data$data, .f, ...)`.

Comment: Now I tried doing it te other way, but I still get the same result. > anova_test(lol, total~Cat)
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `data`.
✖ Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `Cat` doesn't exist.
ℹ Input `data` is `map(.data$data, .f, ...)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is your data is grouped by `Cat` so each group won't see the `Cat` value. You need to ungroup your data

```
lol %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  anova_test(total~Cat)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be the `tibble` that causes the trouble:

Saving your data object as `mydata`, I got this to work:

```
anova_test(as.data.frame(mydata), total ~ Cat)

#Coefficient covariances computed by hccm()
#ANOVA Table (type II tests)
#
#  Effect DFn DFd     F        p p<.05   ges
#1    Cat   2  57 62.17 4.73e-15     * 0.686
```